# WP ie footer is not at the bottom

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8

I have one trouble, on nokia lumia 520 in ie i didn't have my footer at the bottom of the page, but on other ios, android devices all is ok.

why in "mobile" ie i have such trouble?

```
<div class="page-wrap"> 
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
```

and css:

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.page-wrap{
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -70px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: green;
}

.page-wrap:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

footer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
  background: #577abd;
}

@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important;height:320px!important}  //or even without this line
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pmp01rt4/

Answer (score 1):

I tried your fiddle with both Internet Explorer 11 emulation (press F12) and on my Lumia 1520 (screenshot below). I don't see an issue with it.

[image]

However, I would suggest the following, which to my experience works more reliably on mobile browsers:

```css
article{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:calc(100vh - 50px);
  width:100vw;
  background: green;
}

footer{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
  background: #577abd;
}
```

```html
<article></article>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: emulation... ? maybe reall device?

Comment: Like I said, I used a real Lumia 1520, which that screenshot was taken on. I just double checked with emulation _also_, because I didn't have a smaller Windows Phone at hand. It worked fine on both. Is your phone up to date (running 8.1 with ie11)? Did you try if the code I provided worked out better? Could you maybe show screenshots of what's happening on your phone?

Comment: Ilpo's answer is correct. You should use `bottom: 0px;` for a footer that is always on the bottom of a webpage.